# How to connect two firebase projects to a single Android app?

Tags: android, firebase

I have upgraded to the new Firebase System after Google IO 2016 and now I have an app that uses **two build variants** `debug` and `release`.

What i want to do is connect my `Staging-Firebase-Project` with `debug variant` and my `Release-Firebase-Project` with the `release variant` but from [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) i cannot find a way to do this.

If i download and use `google-services.json` file from one project the other one stops working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin#adding_the_json_file).

Since plugin version 2.0.0-alpha3, you can add different .json config files based on the build type.